# An issue with an URLConnection using java

Tags: java, html

I'm trying to read out the code of a website.
But there is an issue if I want to receive the code of this site for example: "https://www.amazon.de/gp/bestsellers/pet-supplies/#2" 
I tried a lot, but still im just receiving the code of  https://www.amazon.de/gp/bestsellers/pet-supplies". So something does not work right as I want to receive place 21-40 and not 1-20.
I'm using an URLConneciton and a BufferedReader:

```
public String fetchPage(String urlS){       
    String s = null;
    String qc = null;

    try{
    URL url = new URL(urlS);
    URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
    uc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));


    while((s = reader.readLine()) != null){
        qc += s;
    }
    reader.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
        qc = "receiving qc failed";
    }
    return qc;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your effort :)

Answer (score 1):

The URL you're fetching, contains an achor (the #2 at the end). An anchor is a client-side concept and is originally used to jump to a certain part of the page. Some webapps (mostly single-page apps) use the anchor to keep track of some sort of state (eg. what page of products you're viewing).

Since the anchor is a **client side concept, the responding webserver (or your browser/HTTP client library) just drops any anchors** as if you actually requested `https://www.amazon.de/gp/bestsellers/pet-supplies`.

Bottom line is that you'll never get the second page... Goog luck in scraping Amazon though ;)